# robot framework - BDD style- No Given present

Tags: api, robotframework, bdd

When writing BDD style test case in robot framework if there is no test or keyword, then what should be written in the Given statement?
I am writing an API test using the BDD style in the robot framework. But for the very first test which will be executed there is no Given statement that will be executed. Is there any placeholder which we can use?
Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no Given statement, then you should skip it. IMHO, You shouldn't write for styling as well. BDDs are meant to express the business requirement and having a dummy G-W-T statement, which doesn't explain a requirement doesn't make sense.

For an example, your BDD should look like

```
When the user registers only with First Name and Last Name 
And doesn't enter Age 
Then the error message "Please enter Age" should be displayed
```

Comment: It seems like in this specific answer, the "Given" part could or should be "Given the user is not registered".

Answer (score 1):

You just skip it, don't write it; or, if you do want to have something - for styling for example, write `Given No Operation`.

Answer (score 1):

There's always some context in which the scenario is taking place. Maybe the application is already running, or already installed, or you're already on the home page. In the case of the API, whatever service you're providing is available.

That context is your `Given`.

The trigger for behaviour - the thing which causes a change to happen - is the event, or the `When`.

It's often the case that when you start up an application or service, a default state is created. There's no trigger for it; it's just how things start. So for instance, you might see something like:

```
Given the Tetris game is running
Then the grid should be empty
```

If your scenario is concerned with whether the game starts up correctly, you can phrase it as a `When`:

```
When I start the game
Then the grid should be empty
```

Even then, there's probably a:

```
Given the game is installed
```

If working with an API, with the assumption that the API is available, I might put a check here to find out whether it really is (yes, I really do mean putting an assertion in the `Given`). If the test fails, it's usually because the service didn't start; which is usually because you've got environment problems. It's a great way to flag it up.

It's also OK to put the step in as English, but leave it empty in code, if you're really confident about the starting state being in good shape.

```
Given I am on Google.com
```

The purpose of scenarios in BDD isn't just to automate tests; it's to illustrate the intent and value of the behaviour using concrete examples. So assume you start with nothing. No internet. No application. No API. What needs to change for your scenario to run? That's your context. It's more common, I've found, to have a missing `When` than a missing `Given`, for those starting scenarios, since no user has triggered anything.

Thinking of your scenarios as living documentation with examples, rather than tests, might help to clarify what you need to include. BDD scenarios are tests as a nice by-product of exploration through conversation, and automating the result.

You might also like this blog post on [4 different ways of handling Givens](https://lizkeogh.com/2008/11/18/four-ways-of-handling-givens/).